# Getting HTML table via pandas read_html won't work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

### What works

I managed to get data from a hmtl table via `pd.read_html` like so:

```py
In[1]:

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

URL = "https://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/"
df_in_list = pd.read_html(URL, attrs = {'id': 'currencies-all'})

# df_in_list has the df in element 0
df_raw = df_in_list[0]  
df = df_in_list[0]  

df = df[['#', 'Name', 'Symbol', 'Market Cap', 'Price' ]]

print(tabulate(df.head(), headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
```

```
Out[1]:

+----+-----+------------------+----------+-----------------+-----------+
|    |   # | Name             | Symbol   | Market Cap      | Price     |
|----+-----+------------------+----------+-----------------+-----------|
|  0 |   1 | BTC Bitcoin      | BTC      | $95,224,161,781 | $5398.69  |
|  1 |   2 | ETH Ethereum     | ETH      | $19,256,205,102 | $182.34   |
|  2 |   3 | XRP XRP          | XRP      | $15,031,762,618 | $0.359679 |
|  3 |   4 | LTC Litecoin     | LTC      | $5,530,275,811  | $90.24    |
|  4 |   5 | BCH Bitcoin Cash | BCH      | $5,514,209,793  | $311.17   |
+----+-----+------------------+----------+-----------------+-----------+
```

Found the div id via Chrome dev tools:

```html
<table class="table floating-header summary-table 
js-summary-table dataTable no-footer" 
id="currencies-all"   <!-- this is what I need -->
style="font-size: 14px; width: 100%;" role="grid">
```

### What does not work

Now trying to get the data from a different URL, but without success. The URL is this:

https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/?start=20130428&end=20190410

The table is in this div:

```
<div id="historical-data" class="tab-pane active">
```

My code is this:

```py
In[2]:

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

URL = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/?start=20130428&end=20190410"
df_in_list = pd.read_html(URL, attrs = {'id': 'historical-data'})

# df_in_list has the df in element 0
df_raw = df_in_list[0]  
df = df_in_list[0]  

df = df[['#', 'Name', 'Symbol', 'Market Cap', 'Price' ]]

print(tabulate(df.head(), headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
```

```
Out[2]:

ValueError: No tables found
```

What am I missing?

### Edit

Obviously there is no `table` tag in this div I am interested in:

```
<div id="historical-data" class="tab-pane active">
```

Is that the cause of the error?

If so, how else can I get the data that is within that div?

### Edit 2

I know that coinmarketcap.com has an API, but I rather prefer getting the data from their website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have the wrong `class` for the table.

If you change `df_in_list` to `df_in_list = pd.read_html(URL, attrs = {'class': 'table'})` it should work.

You'll have to change the `df = df[['#', 'Name', 'Symbol', 'Market Cap', 'Price' ]]` part too, since those columns aren't in the new table you're scraping.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.